# Plotting the normal quantile function with R

Tags: r, normal-distribution, data-visualization

I would like to make a graph of the quantile function of the standard normal distribution using R. I use the command

```
plot(qnorm,ylim=c(-4,4))
```

and I get this graph

[image]

However, the graph that I get is truncated at around $-2$ and around $2$. I would like to see something like this picture

[image]

The last picture was generated using the command

```
plot(1:99999/10^5,qnorm(1:99999/10^5),type="l")
```

but it is inefficient and slow.

Why is R making the truncated graph? What command should I use to make a graph without truncation?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: See the help page for `curve` and pay particular attention to the `n` argument.  For efficient plotting, use the latter method but choose x-values spaced (approximately) inversely in proportion to the derivative of the function you are plotting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be sufficient:

```
plot(qnorm,from=pnorm(-4),to=pnorm(4))
```

If you'd like it a bit smoother where the radius of curvature is small, I'd suggest increasing the `n` parameter a little, e.g.:

```
plot(qnorm,from=pnorm(-4),to=pnorm(4),n=201)
```

see `?plot.function` and `?curve`